# Threads receiving the same ID in C

Tags: c, multithreading, for-loop

Here is a block of code that creates a number of threads provided by the user, each thread then generates a random number and calculates its squareroot.  I cannot figure out why the threads are getting the same ID, line 64 is the culprit as it is where the threads are being created.  I suspect that there is something happening in the loop that is causing the threads to all be generated at the same time.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//
// Zach
//
// 
//
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////



#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>





void *squareroot(void *num1)
{
  int *id = (int *)num1;
  int incoming = rand()/100;
  float *outgoing = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
  printf("%d \n", *id);
  printf("%d\n", incoming);
  *outgoing = 5.000;
  //Calculate the square root of the number passed to the function
  *outgoing = sqrt(incoming);
  return outgoing;

}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])//testing funcion
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  int i, j;
  int *temp = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
  if (argc != 2) 
  {

    printf ("ERROR: Enter a number\n");
    return 1;

  }

  int loop = atoi(argv[1]); //grabbing the integer supplied by user
  pthread_t thread_id[loop];
  void *exit_status;
  float *thread_result;

  for(i = 0; i < loop; i++)
  {

    pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, squareroot, &i);
  }


  for(j = 0; j < loop; j++)
  {
    pthread_join(thread_id[j], &exit_status);
    thread_result = (float *)exit_status;
    printf("%f\n", *thread_result);

  }


}
```

Comment: I also notice that some runs the threads are being joined before all have been created, how can this be?

Comment: Sorry I realize that i took out some stuff before I put it up here.  It is the line:
`for(i = 0; i < loop; i++)
  {

    pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, squareroot, &i);
  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what is happening is that your loop finishes creating all the threads (or at least some of them) before any of the threads actually run and extract their unique id.

Because you're passing a pointer to `i`, when each thread finally gets around to checking its parameter, `i` is already finished...  Or at least partway through.  The danger is that multiple threads might see the same value for `i`.  It's even worse that you never copy the value out of that pointer - you always dereference it.  That means it might change in the middle of your thread's execution.

What you should do instead is pretend it is a pointer:

```
pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, squareroot, (void*)i);
```

And in your thread function:

```
int id = (int)num1;
```

This works because the pointer is passed by value.  Whatever value you provide is the value that goes into the thread function.  Previously it didn't work because you passed a pointer to a value that could change in another thread.

PS: Don't forget to `free` the result from each thread in your loop at the end.  At the moment you're not cleaning up memory that you allocated.

Comment: Thank you I'm going to give this a try.

Comment: This worked, thank you. I am still trying to wrap my head around the passing void pointer to the function.

Comment: Remember it's just a value.  The `void*` is there as a generic datatype.  Normally you would allocate some memory and pass it in, or point into a table or something...  But it's pretty common to throw in some other datatype, provided it fits in the space of `void*`.  Generally that's 32 bits, although if you compile for 64-bit targets a pointer is 64 bits of course.